# Ruby on Rails: how to create a reference to a db table with string as primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to ROR, and now doing a course project related to books.
I have a "book" table with string 'isbn' as its primary key, and now trying to add another "comment" with reference to the book table with a foreign key 'isbn' to refer to the "book" table .
So my "models/comment.rb" looks like this:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book, references: :isbn, type: :string
end
```

And "models/book.rb" is:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My "books" table looks like:
[image: SQLite view for books table]
I would expect that the "comments" table generated will contain a column "isbn" (string) after db migration, but in fact the "comments" table generated contained a "book_id" (integer) instead.
[image]
How can I generate a foreign key to reference to the string primary key "isbn" in "book" table?

Comment: how did you write your migration? with `t.references`?

Comment: I would suggest using id as primary key over using other columns as primary key when you are learning the framework. You should make `isbn` is uniq column and index it and use id as primary key.

Comment: @RafayetMonon Yes with `t.references`.

my migration was like:

`class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :note
      t.references :book, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end`

Comment: @AmitPatel Because I have some tables which are the results of another system and contains only ISBN information, that is why I think using ISBN should be used as the primary key, or are there any possibility of using the conventional way?

Answer (score 3):

Start by setting up the foreign key column to be the right type and set the foreign key constraint to point to the right column:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :note
      t.references :book, type: :string, column_name: :isbn
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

> I would expect that the "comments" table generated will contain a
>   column "isbn" (string) after db migration, but in fact the "comments"
>   table generated contained a "book_id" (integer) instead.

Migrations are actually a lot simpler and dumber than you would think. Its just a DSL that creates SQL statements. Its not actually in any way aware of the other table so it has no way of knowing that `books.isbn` is a string column. It just uses the default type for `add_reference` which is `:integer`. Rails is driven by convention - not artificial intelligence.

If you want to call the column something else like `book_isbn` you have to do it in two steps instead:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :note
      t.string :book_isbn
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_foreign_key :comments, :books, 
       column: "book_isbn", primary_key: "isbn"
  end
end
```

Then setup the books model to use your non-conventional primary key:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :isbn
  has_many :comments, 
    foreign_key: :book_isbn # default is book_id
end
```

On the comment side you need to configure the `belongs_to` association so that it points to `books.isbn` instead of `books.id`.

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book, primary_key: :isbn
end
```

`references` is not a valid option for `belongs_to`.

```
ArgumentError (Unknown key: :references. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :foreign_type, :dependent, :primary_key, :inverse_of, :required, :polymorphic, :touch, :counter_cache, :optional, :default)
```

Comment: Thank you very much max, this is a very clear instruction:)